# C# Datatable not saving in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datatable

I am having a head melt and can't figure out why my Datatable before binded to a gridview is not saving to a Session?

It is always null.

Here is my code. `Session["Data"] = dts;` should contain the Data. however when I go to extract data on gridview sorting it is empty

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    PopulateProductClass();
    PopulateProduct();       
    }
    PopulateOrderList();      
}

private void PopulateOrderList()
{
    DateTime d;
    DateTime d2;

    CustomerInfo ki = CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomerInfoByUserID(CooneenHelper.GetUserImpersonisationID());
    int nKustomerID = ki.CustomerID;
    DataTable dts = new DataTable();
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUName", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("SKUNumber", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemStatus", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemUnitCount", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("mtrx_Code2", typeof(string));

    QueryDataParameters qdp = new QueryDataParameters();
    qdp.Add("@CustomerID", nKustomerID);

    if (drpProductClass.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0" || drpProductClass.SelectedValue.ToString() == null) { qdp.Add("@OrderItemWRClass", drpProductClass.SelectedItem.ToString()); }
    if (drpProduct.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0") { qdp.Add("@OrderItemSKUID", drpProduct.SelectedValue.ToString()); }                
    if (txtStartDate.Text != "") { d = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text); qdp.Add("@OrderItemDateFrom", d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); }
    if (txtEndDate.Text != "") { d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text); qdp.Add("@OrderItemDateTo", d2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); }

    DataSet ds = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_GetOrderItemByCustID", qdp, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
    DataRow drNew = dts.NewRow();
    drNew["OrderDate"] = ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(dr["OrderDate"], DateTime.Now).ToShortDateString();
    drNew["OrderNumber"] = dr["OrderNumber"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemSKUName"] = dr["OrderItemSKUName"].ToString();
    drNew["SKUNumber"] = dr["SKUNumber"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemStatus"] = dr["OrderItemStatus"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemUnitCount"] = dr["OrderItemUnitCount"].ToString();
    drNew["mtrx_Code2"] = dr["mtrx_Code2"].ToString();
    dts.Rows.Add(drNew);
    }

    //Clear the TextBox
    litResults.Text = String.Empty;

    if (dts.Rows.Count == 1)
    litResults.Text = "" + dts.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Order Items";
    else
    litResults.Text = "" + dts.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Order Items";

    gvOrderItems.Visible = true;
    gvOrderItems.DataSource = dts.DefaultView;      
    gvOrderItems.DataBind();

    Session["Data"] = dts;

    if (dts.Rows.Count > 1) litResults.Text += " - Showing page " + (gvOrderItems.PageIndex + 1).ToString() + " of " + gvOrderItems.PageCount.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Did you step through your code to make sure you are setting the session variable and an error did not cause the setter to not be executed? A try catch block would also help you here in debugging.

Comment: Hi codemonkeyliketab yes tried it with `try catch` block and no errors were reported. I can see my datatable `dts` has data inside it. But Session is always empty

Comment: I have also noticed my Session variable is able to save normal string values. But for some datatable is not being saved?

Comment: are you saying if you change the line `Session["Data"] = dts;` to `Session["Data"] = "hello world";` then it works?

Comment: What's session mode you have set???

Comment: Sorry its not saving string values aswell. I am just wondering is it something to with PostBack maybe? Session variables have been used on other parts of the site and seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateOrderList();
}

private void PopulateOrderList()
{
    DateTime d;
    DateTime d2;
    DataTable dts = new DataTable();
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUName", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("SKUNumber", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemStatus", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemUnitCount", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("mtrx_Code2", typeof(string));

        DataRow drNew = dts.NewRow();
        drNew["OrderDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        drNew["OrderNumber"] = "122";
        drNew["OrderItemSKUName"] = "sku";
        drNew["SKUNumber"] = "skunum";
        drNew["OrderItemStatus"] = "Done";
        drNew["OrderItemUnitCount"] = "1290";
        drNew["mtrx_Code2"] ="abc123";
        dts.Rows.Add(drNew);

    Session["Data"] = dts;
    gridview.Visible = true;
    gridview.DataSource = dts.DefaultView;
    gridview.DataBind();


}

protected void gridview_SortCommand(object source, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Data"];
}
```

Comment: The solution works fine now. I am still not sure why it wasn't working? Maybe I was using the wrong syntax for when calling the Session variable?